# Can we extend an existing extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm researching about Visual Studio Code extension. I want to add some more items to `code complete` (IntelliSense) of [Microsoft Python extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python)

I don't know how. I just think out some solutions:
1. Write a new extension for the existing extension `vscode-python` to customize `code complete` items.
-> Can we write an extension for an existing extension?
2. Write a new extension that will adapt the Visual Studio Code editor vs `vscode-python`. In this, I will forward/customize the requests from the editor to `vscode-python` and then customize/insert my items to the responds before return to editor.

I'm researching about VSCode extension so I don't which solution is realizable. Can you help me or give me some hints about another solution.

Comment: I am looking to do something similar for python extension. Did you find any luck with this question?

Comment: I'm the coauthor and maintainer of an Oracle SQL Developer extension. Oracle is abandoning SQL Developer and writing their code as an extension to VS Code. I'd like to extend their extension instead of "competing" with theirs.